# How much does one cup of fresh spinach weigh?

Tags: vegetables

How much fresh spinach is in one cup? When I read articles they always say eat "1 cup of spinach", but I don't know how much spinach that is. I am talking about 4x6 cm leaves.

Comment: What do you mean by "number of spinach"? How many spinach leaves are in a cup?

Comment: The whole point of measuring one cup of anything is to have one cup. If you want to know how many leaves of a certain size make up one cup, I would suggest that you fill one cup with leaves of that size and count them.

Comment: I went ahead and edited this to ask specifically for weight, since obviously you can just measure one cup of volume if you want to. (And the OP doesn't have an account, so I think it's fine to just adopt the question.)

Comment: @jefromi Look at the deleted post, and the older edit, which both came from the OP. It was clear that he doesn't want to know the weight, but the number of the leaves.

Answer (score 6):

How much spinach is in a cup varies widely based on who is doing the measuring, how well the spinach is trimmed, whether it is chopped, the size of the leaves, whether it is cooked, and if it is cooked, how well it is drained.

That said, the FDA calls 1 cup of raw spinach 30 grams.

If you're looking for the number of leaves in a cup, that can't be answered because some leaves are much bigger than others. To measure a cup, you need a cup, a scale (30 grams would work for raw spinach) or to be willing to guess.

**EDIT** Now that you've added the size of the leaves, the question is answerable, but I would need leaves that size and a cup in order to answer.

Comment: I still don't agree that it is especially well answerable. Just picked leaves will have a very different density from limp leaves towards wilting. And of course there will be some variance depending on just how you picked them up, and if you squeezed them a bit or not.

Comment: @rumtscho Yeah, for really repeatable results I'd recommend a scale, but it's hard to imagine an application that would require that kind of precision.

Comment: Anything that would actually require a certain number of leaves (like a canape? I don't even know) would just call for that number, I'd think.

Comment: I think it's totally fine that the answer is "it's hard to say, here's a really rough guess". I did edit the question to specifically ask about weight since it was unclear.

Comment: I note that http://www.cookitsimply.com/measurements/cups/spinach-raw-0070-0c210.html lists 1 cup as 225 grams - which is *huge* difference.